# Tool in Tool Palette as a parameter for Button

Tags: arcpy, python-addin, parameters, global

I built a simple toolbar with Tool Palette and Button.
Button should make a selection according to a global parameter which can be set by selection of Value in Palette box.

[image]

I.e. if I choose number "1", pressing the button on the right will select layer by attribute value like  for example "PAR =1".

I tried something like this:

```
class ONE(object):
    """Implementation for SelectNlevelTest_addin.ONE (Tool)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.shape = "NONE"
        global par
    def onMouseDown(self, x, y, button, shift):
        global par
        par = "par = 1"
    def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
        pass
    def onMouseUp(self, x, y, button, shift):
        global par
        par = "par = 1"
    def onMouseUpMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
        pass
    def onMouseMove(self, x, y, button, shift):
        pass
    def onMouseMoveMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
        pass
    def onDblClick(self):
        pass
    def onKeyDown(self, keycode, shift):
        pass
    def onKeyUp(self, keycode, shift):
        pass
    def deactivate(self):
        pass
    def onCircle(self, circle_geometry):
        pass
    def onLine(self, line_geometry):
        pass
    def onRectangle(self, rectangle_geometry):
        pass
```

But setting PAR in defs `onMouseUp` and `onMouseDown` doesn't help, it tells that value 'par' is not defined.
If I set PAR in `def __init__(self)`, it makes selection, but only by one parameter ignoring pressing other number.

Is that possible to set the parameter by pressing the button from Tool Palette?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
par = ''    
class ONE(object):
    """Implementation for SelectNlevelTest_addin.ONE (Tool)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.shape = "NONE"
        global par
    def onMouseDown(self, x, y, button, shift):
        global par
        par = "par = 1"
```

But this is way better:

```
class ONE(object):
    """Implementation for SelectNlevelTest_addin.ONE (Tool)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.shape = "NONE"
        self.par = ''
    def onMouseDown(self, x, y, button, shift):
        self.par = "par = 1"
```